# text align in textarea via php through button

Tags: php, css, database, button, textarea

I have a button which uses php to connect to a db and displays 2 different values in the same textarea. Is it possible to get the first value to align on the left and the second value to align on the right in the same textarea? If yes, how?

Comment: Please post your code and we will try to help you

Comment: Er... Yes, it is possible. Give `text-align: left` and `text-align: right` for the `textarea`s. And please go and eat something!

Comment: so your question is about html and css. php ,database is irrelevant

Comment: @FastSnail Reverted.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I gather from the post it's one textarea and two different bits of text. You can't assign CSS to specific values inside the textarea, only the textarea itself.

Comment: @awl19 Ah! True that.

Comment: @PraveenKumar it's only one textarea tho and yeah I'm going to eat sth thanks for your concern

Comment: create a div and 2 span tags inside div.then align one span left outer right

Comment: Use CKEditor instead of textarea.